# Swipe Gesture Recognizer at ScrollView (Paging)

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, swipe-gesture

This is what I have on my Interface Builder using xcode 6.1.1

[image]

I have programmatically inserted 3 pages into ScrollView. I am able to swipe left and right to change page without issue.

```
        var view1 = UIView();
        view1.frame.size = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height);
        view1.frame.origin = CGPointMake((self.view.frame.width * 0), 0);
        view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();

        var view2 = UIView();
        view2.frame.size = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height);
        view2.frame.origin = CGPointMake((self.view.frame.width * 1), 0);
        view2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor();

        var view3 = UIView();
        view3.frame.size = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height);
        view3.frame.origin = CGPointMake((self.view.frame.width * 2), 0);
        view3.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor();

        scrollView.addSubview(view1);
        scrollView.addSubview(view2);
        scrollView.addSubview(view3);
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width * 3, scrollView.frame.size.height);
```

What I need now is to detect swipe gesture on ScrollView. So far I have Swipe Gesture Recognizer works well on navigation bar and tab bar, but not the ScrollView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `UIScrollView` has its own gesture recognizer you need to tell it to recognize another gesture recognizer:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

See the [Controlling Simultaneous Gesture Recognition](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:) 
in the `UIGestureRecognizerProtocol` documentation.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Where should I place this snippet of code? I placed it in my view controller but it doesn't seem to work. My view controller did extends UIGestureRecognizerDelegate.

Comment: Yes, in the view controller class. And make sure that the view controller class conforms to `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol (where this method belongs to). And there is no guarantee for this to work, maybe there are more steps necessary,

Comment: Thanks! I added the Swipe Recognizer programmatically instead of using Interface Builder and it works! Anyway, should it work even if I use swipe gesture from interface builder?